# Change that convoluted font mesh

Tags: mesh, topology

[image]

hi! haha, the example is a bit simple but converted font meshes tend to be so complex as more complex the fonts you use. and i saw a vid tutorial [if not for completely forgetting what tutorial it was again :( ]
that tutorial shows how to neatly 'gridify' the mesh which i think is so useful.

[image]~ something like this

could anyone share how you do this? thanks!~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve this type of topology (although it is not perfect) using the ***Remesh Modifier***.
[image]

First extrude yout text mesh a bit.
[image]

Go to *Object Mode* and enable the ***Remesh Modifier***
[image]

In *Object* header, in the *Display* panel check the ***Wire*** checkbox. It'll allow you to see how the modifier works in a realtime.
[image]

Uncheck the ***Remove Disconected Pieces*** checkbox (if you don't some of the letters may dissapear) and play with the modifier's settings.
[image]

At the end delete the previously extruded vertices.

Comment: this is the tutorial i forgot hahaha the block one is cool

Comment: Yeah, blocks option is very cool, especially if you're a Minecraft's fan :).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make a grid-plane. Make some text. Extrude the text in its modifier panel. Then place the text through the plane.

Convert the text to mesh from curve/meta/surf/text. Pick the plane, go to modifiers, add a Boolean modifier. Select the text as your second object.

Hit space again, and convert the boolean to mesh from curve/meta/surf/text. Delete the plane object and the original text object. Now you just have the gridded version.

---

Note that **this does add the grid, but it doesn't make it a great mesh**. I've drawn on some messy parts in blue, red and pink, where you don't have neat triangles or quads:

[image]

Personally, I think I'd rather manually create bridges, and get a better edgeflow. But maybe you've got a different goal or workflow.

Comment: yes, i agree with that but the grid you could make on the fonts is def. way better,  thanks!